# grub-mkrescue 2.06 giving issues when creating an iso from directory

Tags: linux, boot, bash, grub

## It worked before

Hello, I have been working on my own Operating System for awhile now and recently I came back after a break to find that `grub-mkrescue` is unable to create an .iso file from my disk directory.

## The issue now

The exact command ran:

```bsh
# /bin/bash

# Why are you the problem child?
grub-mkrescue -o FluxedOS.iso isodir
```

The exact output:

```
mcopy: No directory slots
grub-mkrescue: error: `mcopy` invocation failed
.
```

## What is in isodir

```
isodir
├── boot
│   ├── FluxedOS.bin
│   └── grub
│       └── grub.cfg
└── programs
    ├── dir.exc
    ├── README.md
    └── test.exc
```

## What is in grub.cfg

```
set timeout=0
set default=0

menuentry "FluxedOS" {

    multiboot2 /boot/FluxedOS.bin
    boot

}
```

## More Info

Its not just my OS! I can not build any OS that uses grub2 and turns it into a iso.

## Does anyone have any info on how I can turn isodir into a .iso file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with mtools version 4.0.32 - https://bugs.archlinux.org/index.php?do=details&task_id=71547

If you downgrade mtools to 4.0.31 it should work as a temporary fix.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1983604